# php setting value of drop down and radio button with data fetched from database

Tags: javascript, php, html

Started coding in php few days back and am facing following issue.
As the php page loads, am getting details from table and trying to set value of a drop down based on that value that I get from the table.

```
<select  title= "Fruit selected" name="fruit" id="fruit">
<option value="none selected">-Select Fruit-</option>
<?php if(!is_null($user)){ if($user['fruit']=="apple"){echo '<option value="apple" selected="selected">Apple</option>'}}else{echo '<option value="apple">Apple</option>'}?>
<?php if(!is_null($user)){ if($user['grad_semister']=="banana"){echo '<option value="banana" selected="selected">Banana</option>'}}else{echo '<option value="banana">Banana</option>'}?>
</select>
```

I believe am doing fundamentally stupid according to php and I am not good at fundamentals. Can someone throw some light on what could be wrong? As of now when I go to the php page with above code, I get **HTTP error 500**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the **;** after each **echo**.

It should be:

```
<?php if(!is_null($user)){ if($user['fruit']=="apple"){echo '<option value="apple" selected="selected">Apple</option>';}}else{echo '<option value="apple">Apple</option>';}?>
<?php if(!is_null($user)){ if($user['grad_semister']=="banana"){echo '<option value="banana" selected="selected">Banana</option>';}}else{echo '<option value="banana">Banana</option>';}?>
```

Comment: Exactly.  I was testing my ocde on Phpfiddle as I received this answer.

Answer (score 0):

That probably not the php code error maybe your entire scripts or pages on server side have problem.

Comment: If I remove that php code and write plain old html code <option value="apple">apple</option>, page loads

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer well the GEt Method and $user[] and see what will happenn.